# c# IDataReader SqlDataReader difference

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, idatareader

Can someone tell me the difference between these two pieces of code? Why use IDataReader?

```
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // get data from the reader
    }
}

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // get data from the reader
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

`SqlDataReader` implements the interface `IDataReader`. So do all other ADO.NET drivers (Oracle, MySql, etc). You can use `IDataReader`, so that if you plan to change database engine some day, you don't have to rewrite all your `SqlDataReader` references.

The same goes for `IDbConnection`, `IDbCommand`, etc. Of course when *creating* the connection, you'll need to specify what engine you're using, but aside from that you'll never have to explicitly define which database engine you're using.

Note that `IDataReader` does not have the `HasRows` property, and you have to use the `Create...()` methods to create Commands and Parameters:

```
IDbCommand command = myDbConnection.CreateCommand();
```

Instead of:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(myDbConnection);
```

EDIT: Instead of using the interfaces you may want to use the abstract class `DbConnection` all ADO.NET providers inherit from. They provide some additional features such as getting schema information, and the aforementioned `HasRows` property for the `DbDataReader`. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/759fa77b-8269-4c4a-be90-3c2bdce61d92/ for why the interface hasn't kept up with the abstract class.

Comment: Great answer, you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

The IDataReader and IDataRecord interfaces allow an inheriting class to implement a DataReader class, which provides a means of reading one or more forward-only streams of result sets [For more details see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx)